# matching time on real-time graph

Tags: android, datetime, android-graphview

I set time/date as a x value in my real-time graph, but the time didn't match with my android's time, can someone check my code

```
final DateFormat sdf = android.text.format.DateFormat.getTimeFormat(this);
    graph.getGridLabelRenderer().setLabelFormatter(new DefaultLabelFormatter() {
        @Override
        public String formatLabel(double value, boolean isValueX) {
            if (isValueX) {
                long Valuemilis = (new Double(value)).longValue();
                return sdf.format(Valuemilis*1000);
            }
            else {
                return null;
            }
        }
    });
```

[app's picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Bh0h1.jpg)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get your system time in milliseconds you can use `Date.java` class. 
The below snippet of code may solve your problem.

```
long Valuemilis = new Date().getTime();
```

Comment: the time is suitable, but the same date/time appears at the beginning and end of the graph. It would be nice to match the times, i.e. showing the most recent data-in value as the current time and the previous data values as the times when they were plotted.

Comment: I'm not sure what exactly you want to do. Can you explain a bit more?

Comment: I want to create a real time graph that displays temperature data according to the time when the temperature occurs. So users can see the temperature data an hour earlier or more.

Comment: So you need to match time values with temperature and store them into database. You will have the table which will have the next columns: `id`, `date_with_time` and `temperature`. In the `date_with_time` column just store long values of time in millis and when showing just convert it.